# laravel-selenium phpunit error

Tags: php, laravel, selenium

I installed phpunit-selenium using composer. selenium server is running and still get error selenium server is not running at port 4444. i ran "java -jar selenium-*.jar -port 4444". laravel-IDE created tests are being tested. please take a look at attached inmages. any help will be appreciated.

```
  $ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -port 4444
 20:28:08.048 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75'
 20:28:08.052 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
 2017-02-13 20:28:08.135:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1162ms
 20:28:08.381 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
 20:28:08.382 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped:
 Unable to create new instances on this machine.
 20:28:08.382 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
 20:28:08.383 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
 20:28:08.405 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform WIN8_1
 2017-02-13 20:28:08.576:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
 2017-02-13 20:28:08.768:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6cc4c815{/,null,AVAILABLE}
 2017-02-13 20:28:08.879:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@724af044{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4444}
 2017-02-13 20:28:08.881:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @1908ms
 20:28:08.881 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

and here is how i ran my test.

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit tests/functionTesting/device/addDeviceTest.php --verbose
PHPUnit 5.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.6
Configuration: D:\xampps\htdocs\adexpress-laravel-web\phpunit.xml

S                                                                  1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 1 minute, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 skipped test:

1) addDeviceTest::testMyTestCase
The Selenium Server is not active on host localhost at port 4444.

D:\xampps\htdocs\adexpress-laravel-web\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:299
D:\xampps\htdocs\adexpress-laravel-web\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:337
D:\xampps\htdocs\adexpress-laravel-web\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:314

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Skipped: 1.
```

and my selenium created test is

```
<?php
class addDeviceTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("chrome");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://local.adexpress-web.com/");
  }

  public function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->open("/devices");
    $this->click("//button[@onclick=\"showModel('devices/create')\"]");
    sleep(10);
    $this->type("name=name", "testing device");
    $this->select("name=orientation", "label=Landscape");
    $this->select("name=store_id", "label=Dena Kilback");
    $this->type("name=aisle", "345546577");
    $this->click("id=add_form_save");
    sleep(10);
    $this->click("css=button.confirm");
  }
}
?>
```

This is the error that occurred when I ran phpunit test.

[image]

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere? This is not a site for requests like "I need general help getting my code to work"

Comment: @jdv i guess its a questions. i am stuck in selenium is not working at port 4444 and selenium is running actually.

Comment: Since this has turned into a question about a networked app, you should probably share your OS details.

Comment: So, assuming Selenium is reporting things right, you are running Windows 8.1. Further, it looks like Selenium is binding to port 4444 on any interface. Therefore, this looks like an app-level networking problem, probably associated with a firewall setting. Disable the Windows 8 firewall completely and try again.